# Standalone Bluetooth controller recommendation

Tags: bluetooth

For a hardware project, I'm looking for a simple, robust Bluetooth controller on which I can solder buttons. I found the [Bluefruit EZ-Key](http://www.adafruit.com/product/1535) but I don't like it that I can't change the name.

I've Googled quite a lot but cannot find any alternative. Are there any other standalone Bluetooth controllers around? Or is it possible to build one yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Bear labs has quite a few options. I have used the Blend micro and didn't encounter any problems. I am fairly certain you can change the name too.

http://redbearlab.com/blendmicro/

They also have smaller/larger models